# WPF Style Trigger with targetname not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an issue setting the Foreground color in a ControlTemplate with triggers.

```
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemDefaultBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#FFF" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#EEE" />
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemSelectBackgroundBrush" Color="#69C" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" Color="#79C" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border
                                    Name="tabBorder"
                                    MinWidth="150"
                                    MinHeight="50"
                                    Margin="0,0,20,0"
                                    Background="{StaticResource TabItemDefaultBackgroundBrush}"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="1,1,1,1">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid >
                                            <TextBlock Name="HeaderHeader">
                                                </TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter
                                            x:Name="ContentSite"
                                            Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            ContentSource="Header"
                                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="HeaderHeader" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="tabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItemSelectBackgroundBrush}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

When the tab is selected, the background border 'tabBorder' is set correctly, but the foreground of textblock 'HeaderHeader' does not respond.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="HeaderHeader" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter TargetName="tabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItemSelectBackgroundBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

When I remove the `TargetName` and set the foreground white (to all components), it does work. (but obviously also the foreground color of everything in the content pre

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter TargetName="tabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItemSelectBackgroundBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Even stranger, when I put the `TargetName` back in place, but change the setter property from foreground to background, it DOES work! Then the background is set to white for the selected tab.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="HeaderHeader" Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter TargetName="tabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItemSelectBackgroundBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Why on earth is it not working for what I need (=set foreground for selected tab)?!

Comment: Bind your TextBlock Foreground property to Forground of the control: `<TextBlock Foreground={Binding Forground}>` and set forground without targetname. see the result.

Comment: I can't set the foreground without the targetname, because then the foreground will be inherited by all controls in the tabitem, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I learned something today... I was looking in the wrong direction ! After googling more on "ControlTemplate" something finally sunk in. The `ContentPresenter` does not show the information of the tab, it shows **the label of the tab** and nothing more. So my trigger was working just fine, but it was setting the foreground of a textblock which had no meaning at all!

When I change the trigger to which control actually shows the label, it was easy peasy...

```
<Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" />
```

I did have to use an attached property 'TextElement' in order to be able to set properties on text elements.